# Postgresql reference a variable within statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I come across this scenario frequently in sql and I have seen it done, but would like to summarize the case when/when not to reference a new variable within a statement.

1. This doesn't work -

```
SELECT 
COUNT(id) AS total_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS distinct_id,
total_id - distinct_id AS var
FROM mytable
```

2. but this does -

```
SELECT 
COUNT(id) AS total_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS distinct_id,
COUNT(id) - COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS var
FROM mytable
```

How can I implement scenario 1?

Comment: You can reference a named variable outside the query [select total_id from (select count(id) as total_id from mytable)z]. It makes sense when you need to, but is not needed in your example above.

Comment: what's wrong with second query? that's how you do it in sql

Comment: very simple use case above - applying to above, how would that look?

Comment: Your misconception might be to think an alias is like a variable in a procedural language. It is not. It just determines the name of the column in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery.

```
PostgreSQL:
SELECT total_id, distinct_id, (total_id + distinct_id) as var FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_id, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS distinct_id
    FROM mytable
) as m
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you!